# Query executes in 4 seconds directly in SQL Server but takes > 30 seconds in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query (*about 1600 lines stored as a Stored Procedure*) that takes about 3 seconds to execute (after optimizing it by adding the correct indexes), when executed inside SQL Server Management Studio.

I wrote a wrapper for this in C# and provided myself with the ability to use a URI to execute this query. However, this takes more than 30 seconds to execute and because of this, when I run this query as part of a loop, the browser stalls due to too many pending requests. I wrote the wrapper like this:

```
try
{
   string ConString = Constants.connString;

   using (con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
   {
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
      con.Open();
      dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      while (dr.Read())
      {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

My connection string is this:

```
Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

I know the query itself is good because I've run it multiple times inside SSMS and it worked fine (under 5 seconds on an average). And, I'd be happy to provide with more debug information, except that I don't know what to provide.

To troubleshoot such problems, where would I start?

**EDIT:**

I ran SQL Profiler and collected some stats. This is what I am observing. Very strange that it is the exact query being executed. Let me know if there is anything else I can do at this point.

[image]

Comment: Between what line and what line takes 30 seconds?

Comment: @MikeChristensen: It stalls at `cmd.ExecuteReader()`.

Comment: Are you saying that the SQL command string is 1600 lines, or that it returns 1600 rows?

Comment: Is it plain SQL Text sent from C# code, or Stored Procedure saved in SQL Server and just invoked using ADO.NET?

Comment: You could try running the SQL Server Profiler to see how quickly the query makes it to the server, and then just how long it actually takes to execute.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: It is 1600 lines but most of this is because of enumerating the column names. The actual logic itself is simple.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: It is plain SQL Text that is sent from C#.

Comment: Why would you send 1600 lines of SQL code instead of having a stored procedure and invoking it?

Comment: @istepaniuk: You're right. This is in a test environment and I'll convert this into a SP later.

Comment: So maybe you should skip performance testing for later as well? ... What is the point of testing a thing, that's going to be changed in a while?

Comment: @Legend That's a pretty freakin big command string to be pushing to the server every time you loop.  And if most of those lines are column names, I can tell you that 1000+ columns is one heckuva lot of columns to be returning to the client.  That's way outside of the normal bounds.

Comment: Ok; I guess I'll spend some time creating an SP on the server. I am thinking this is not the actual problem but I'll make the change anyways. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I made all the changes suggested and ran SQL profiler. Updated my question with details. Observe how the .NET Client takes > 18 seconds whereas SSMS takes only 3 seconds.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736638/sql-query-slow-in-net-application-but-instantaneous-in-sql-server-management-st

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok; Finally, found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187150/executing-stored-proc-from-dotnet-takes-very-long-but-in-ssms-it-is-immediate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736638/sql-query-slow-in-net-application-but-instantaneous-in-sql-server-management-st). Answer replicated here for convenience. Thanks goes to the original poster, [Jacques Bosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269512/jacques-bosch), who in turn took it from [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/sql-server/353cb16c-3cde-44dd-a264-750c1ce4e423/sql-server-query-analyzer-runs-fast--stored-procedure-runs-slow.aspx). Cannot believe this problem was solved in 2004!

The problem seems to be caused by SQL Server's [Parameter Sniffing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/31/565991.aspx).
To prevent it, just assign your incoming parameter values to other variables declared right at the top of your SP.

[See this nice Article about it](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=email-main&utm_content=Sniffing-201010116&utm_campaign=SQL)

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure
(
    @Param1 INT
)
AS

declare @MyParam1 INT
set @MyParam1 = @Param1

SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ColumnName = @MyParam1 

GO
```

I copied this information from [eggheadcafe.com](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/353cb16c-3cde-44dd-a264-750c1ce4e423/sql-server-query-analyzer.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Queries often run faster within SQL Server management studio due to caching of query plans.  Try running sp_recompile on your stored procedure before benchmarking.  This will clear the query plan.

More details can be found here: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't U use XML instead of a Result Set ?
As far as I know using XML is much faster than Reading a result set.
so in this case you should use something like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table Name]
FOR XML PATH('[Your Path]'), ELEMENTS XSINIL, ROOT('Your Root')
```

and after that I think you can serialize it in your Project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, and it turned out that the difference was caused by the `ARITHABORT` setting that is different if you connect via SQL management studio. The .net connection set the `ARITHABORT` setting to `OFF`, while SQL management studio sets this setting to `ON`.

You can try if you have the same problem by executing `SET ARITHABORT OFF` in the SQL Management Studio, and then execute your query.

[Here is a thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/0c861af2-1991-4d93-bd24-1eda8698053f/) that explains why this setting can cause such dramatic performance differences.