# Stored procedure timesout called from code, executes ok from SSMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, connection-timeout

I have stored procedure which takes around 10 seconds to run when called from SSMS and executes successfully. The procedure takes an `int` as a parameter.

When calling the same stored procedure from code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringName))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", connection))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@itemId", itemId));
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 150;

        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  
The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
```

The passed parameter is valid and when calling the stored procedure from SSMS with the same parameter value it executes correctly.

Comment: How long does it take when you execute from SSMS?

Comment: @shA.t Removed that line and I get the same exception, only faster.

Comment: By using `cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;` you will never see that error, But your problem is inside of your stored procedure that needs some edits ;).

Comment: Indeed, setting cmd.CommandTimeout = 0 solves the problem and I would mark it as an answer. However, the execution time of calling the SP takes about 30 seconds, much more than calling it from SSMS. Any tips on that one?

Comment: I suggest you to ask another question and add code of your stored procedure to optimize it (or check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3070653/4519059)) ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid that error just use:

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

> **Note :**
>   Your query execution will takes infinitive time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot to specify the direction of the parameter, as you can provide input and output parameters. Try if this works:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@itemId", itemId);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```