# Entity Framework queries are slow on one server but fast on another

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple C# console application that uses Entity Framework 6.1 to access a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. When I run this application on two different servers,  database reads take significantly longer on one of these servers compared to the other, even though they read from the same database. More specifically, each query takes around ½ second longer on the slow server.

So far I have come to the following conclusions:

- When reading from the same database using sqlcmd, the performance is similar on both servers. Therefore, network performance is not the issue.
- Both servers run Windows Server 2008 R2 and .NET 4.5.1. Furthermore, they have the same network settings displayed by "netsh int tcp show global" (I investigated the latter due to this question [.NET to remote SQL Server slow on one machine, not the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869824/net-to-remote-sql-server-slow-on-one-machine-not-the-other)).
- The Entity Framework log (enabled in app.config) and SQL Server Profiler show that the ½ second delay on the slow server occurs before the generated SQL query is sent to SQL Server.
- The delay occurs only when the Entity Framework query contains a parameter which is not known at compile time, i.e. dbContext.SomeDbSet.Where(e => e.Id == 5) is fast since 5 is known at compile time, whereas dbContext.SomeDbSet.Where(e => e.Id == id) since the variable id is not known at compile time. This indicates that parameterized queries are generated from scratch every time.

Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the hardware the same on both servers?

Comment: Have you tried running the queries multiple times? When a linq to sql query has a parameter it is cached differently to if it is a constant, perhaps the caching is the difference.

Comment: No. The server on which Entity Framework is slow is a physical machine, whereas the other is virtual. I am pretty sure that the hardware of the physical server is actually faster. However, we can ignore the hardware since Entity Framework performed just fine on both servers around three months ago.

Comment: @Paul: Yes, when making the performance comparison, I run the exact same parameterized query (the parameter is also the same) 25 times.

Comment: Surely on a fast enough machine you would expect the virtual / in memory system to be faster as it is all in memory, perhaps you could build another virtual machine and test it on there... the real point is you cannot accurately compare two machines when there are sooooo many variations between them.

Comment: I am confident that something is wrong on the server on which EF performs badly, i.e. that it is not just a matter of different hardware, for the following reasons: a) EF performance used to be just fine on this server, b) the hardware is most likely faster on this server, c) EF is much slower on this server - around 25 times slower for reads and 100 times slower for writes.