# .NET to remote SQL Server slow when connected through VPN

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6, windows-7-x64

My sql server Insert/Update is taking lot of time when I am connected to the SQL server on the DEV server (Windows server 2012) from my local machine(Windows 7 - 64 bit) through VPN. Whereas when the application is deployed to the server, it's working fast and nice. I am using Entity framework 6.

I tried the solution from [.NET to remote SQL Server slow on one machine, not the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869824/net-to-remote-sql-server-slow-on-one-machine-not-the-other/), but couldn't get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue, One of the Knockout js file in the solution has a reference to a url that can be reached only through internet, whereas my client VPN cannot access the internet as per the client policy and configuration. So when the application is executing , its trying to communicate to the external server till the maximum retry count is reached and fails, that's where the lag is.

The second culprit is nuget, its trying to access the missing packages through internet too. Once i removed the external URl's from knockout js file and removed nuget from the solution, its nice and fast as usual.

The reason its working fast from the server is , its in the client network with internet access